# Disable future date selection in GWT DateBox

Tags: gwt, datebox

I am using GWT DateBox widget. I would like to know that how to disable future date selection to user in GWT DateBox ?
please provide me answer..

Answer (score 0):

```
DateBox dateBox=new DateBox();
DateTimeFormat simple_date_frmt= DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm");
String date=simple_date_fmt.format(new Date());
dateBox.setEndDate(date);
```

Comment: I have found above solution to disable future date from GWT DateBox widget. I have used DateTimeFormat class to format current date.

Comment: Which `DateBox` is this?! There's no `setEndDate` in GWT's `DateBox`: http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/datepicker/client/DateBox.html